# Building a wrapper directive (wrap some content / component) in angular2

Tags: html, angular, angular2-directives, angular-template

I'm pretty new building directives with Angular2. What I want is to create a popup directive that will wrap the content with some css classes.

**Content**

Content can be pure text and headers like:

```
<div class="data">
    <h2>Header</h2>
    Content to be placed here.
</div>
```

Then I want to give this a directive attribute like: **popup**

```
<div class="data" popup>
    <h2>Header</h2>
    Content to be placed here.
</div>
```

What the directive should do, is to wrap the div inside, lets say:

```
<div class="some class">
    <div class="some other class">
        <div class="data">
            <h2>Header</h2>
            Content to be placed here.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The case i described so far, is this a attribute or structural directives.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: `[popup]`
})

export class PopupDirective {


}
```

Answer (score 24):

The other answer is related but different.

For something closer, see this: [How to conditionally wrap a div around ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593973/how-to-conditionally-wrap-a-div-around-ng-content/41727533) - my solution is for Angular 4, but the linked question has some hints about how this might be doable for Angular 2.

I solved this problem with a component and a directive combined.  My component looks something like this:

```
import { Component, Input, TemplateRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-wrapper-container',
  template: `
<div class="whatever">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template"></ng-container>
</div>
`
})
export class WrapperContainerComponent {
  @Input() template: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

and my directive like this:

```
import { Directive, OnInit, Input, TemplateRef, ComponentRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[myWrapperDirective]'
})
export class WrapperDirective implements OnInit {

  private wrapperContainer: ComponentRef<WrapperContainerComponent>;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    const containerFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(WrapperContainerComponent);
    this.wrapperContainer = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(containerFactory);
    this.wrapperContainer.instance.template = this.templateRef;
  }
}
```

To be able to load your component dynamically, you need to list your component as an [`entryComponent`](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#when-do-i-add-components-to-entrycomponents) inside your module :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  declarations: [WrapperContainerComponent, WrapperDirective],
  exports: [WrapperContainerComponent, WrapperDirective],
  entryComponents: [WrapperContainerComponent]
})
export class MyModule{}
```

so the HTML in the end is:

```
<some_tag *myWrapperDirective />
```

Which renders as:

```
<my-wrapper-container>
  <div class="whatever">
    <some_tag />
  </div>
</my-wrapper-container>
```

Comment: Where does control come from in the @Input set method? Also, where does SubmissionGroup come from? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Wow.  That's due to some bad copy pasting from the actual project I did this for.  I'll clean it up when I have a few...

Comment: This is the relevant answer, can't understand the +7 on the other one...

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup on this @n00dl3 - there was some hasty copy and paste work and I just keep losing track of this, I'm not working in Angular 4 as much ATM

Comment: What is `FormInputContainerComponent`? Should that be `WrapperContainerComponent` in this example?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work (copied exactly, except changing `FormInputContainerComponent` as mentioned above). No errors but It rendered as `<!---->`. Any idea what I did wrong? (Or have a working Plunkr?)

Comment: Getting closer...  Helps when you use ` *myWrapperDirective` instead of `*myWraperDirective` :) Surprised it didn't give an error that it didn't recognize that name.

Comment: It looks like when you wrap an input in this way, `#` element references don't work correctly. For example, this always shows null for the errors:
`<input type="text" name="age" #ageRef="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="age" required *myWrapperDirective />
<pre>{{ageRef?.errors | json}}</pre>`
It works if you wrap both the `<input>` and the code that uses the element ref in the same `<div *myWrapperDirective>` ... but that doesn't work if you need the element ref throughout the parent component. Any idea how to "export" the element ref for use outside of the directive?

Comment: There is any way to make it work with projection (ng-content) rather than *ngTemplateOutlet please?

Answer (score 9):

You can achieve this with a component attribute selector and Angular 2 Content Projection `<ng-content>`

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div class="app"> 
        <div class="data" myWrapper>
            <h2>Header</h2>
            Content to be placed here.
        </div> 
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {}


@Component({
  selector: '[myWrapper]',
  template: `
    <div class="my-class">
      <div class="my-sub-class">
          <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class MyComponent {

}
```

Comment: This obviously applies only to elements that accept content. It won't work when used on an input element, for that matter.

Comment: This doesn't actually seem to do what @Mikkel is asking. This will wrap the inside of the elemnt the [myWrapper] is placed on, not wrap that template around the info it is placed on.

Comment: This works just fine. Used this with angular 7. But one more thing, instead of directive, use it as a component as [compname] is not recommended by angular style guide.

Comment: This is not what is asked for - this wraps content of elemen with directive and NOT ACTUAL component with directive. In your example `<div class="data" myWrapper>` should be wrapped.