# How to use multiple ng-content in the same component in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives

I would like to display different template in my component. Only one will show.
If `hasURL` is `true`, I want to show the `<a></a>`.
If `hasURL` is `false`, I want to show the `<button></button>`.

The problem if hasURL is false, the component show button, but the ng-content is empty. Because it's already read in the first "`a></a>`

Is there a way to solve that please?

```
        <a class="bouton" href="{{ href }}" *ngIf="hasURL">
            <ng-content>
            </ng-content>
        </a>

        <button class="bouton" *ngIf="!hasURL">
            <ng-content>
            </ng-content>    
        </button>
```

Answer (score 132, accepted):

You can wrap `ng-content` in `ng-template` and use `ngTemplateOutlet`

```
<a class="bouton" href="{{ href }}" *ngIf="hasURL">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl"></ng-container>
</a>

<button class="bouton" *ngIf="!hasURL">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl"></ng-container> 
</button>
<ng-template #contentTpl><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
```

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/fQkEz2HQfOLZhhEkNr0Q?p=preview)**

See also

- [How to conditionally wrap a div around ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593973/how-to-conditionally-wrap-a-div-around-ng-content)

**[Angular 9 demo](https://ng-run.com/edit/N7cnnC9HCm1cKlE88QFp)**

Comment: Thanks! It works great. I'm still with Angular 2 not Angular 4, so I had to use `<template>` instead `<ng-template>`

Comment: @dude Can you check this https://ng-run.com/edit/N7cnnC9HCm1cKlE88QFp?

Comment: My mistake, it actually seems to work, but you can not output ng-content twice, only when wrapping it in *ngIf as mentioned here, sorry.

Comment: Why can't we use <ng-content></ng-content> in multiple templates?

Comment: Note: using `<ng-content></ng-content>` and `<ng-content select="something"></ng-content>`. Both should be in their own `<ng-template></ng-template>`.