# How to render multiple ng-content inside an ngFor loop using Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to display two differents `ng-content` inside two `ngFor` loops.
But as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35192483/7259343) answer, Angular can't project ng-content multiple times.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699654/7259343) solution, but this does not allow me to project multiple times my content, only to display it at different places depending on an `ngIf` condition.

Here's my actual code :

An example parent component (any component using app-table). That's what I want to do.

```
<app-table [data]="myData">
  <div lineHeader let-line>
    {{line.name}}
  </div>
  <div lineContent let-element>
    {{element.name}}
  </div>
</app-table>
```

The child component (app-table). Here I can do everything while the parent component keeps working the same way.

```
<div *ngFor="let line of data">
  <ng-content select="[lineHeader]"></ng-content>
  <div *ngFor="let element of line">
    <ng-content select="[lineContent]"></ng-content>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I tried this solution` That solution should help you. There is also another solution

Comment: Please recheck your code, there are multiple errors. Your property binding (select="[lineHeader]") is wrong. You need to put the square brackets around the property (**[select]="lineHeader"**).

Comment: @dave0688 No no no no )))

Comment: `let-` is only supported on template elements and i don't get how you make for loop `let line of data` and then `let element of line` Where are you going to take `line.name`?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The best option in your case would be trancluding `ng-template` by using `ngTemplateOutlet` like:

```html
<app-table [data]="myData">
  <ng-template #lineHeader let-line>
    <div>
     {{line.name}}
    </div>
  </ng-template>
   <ng-template #lineContent let-element>
    <div>
      {{element.name}}
    </div>
   </ng-template>
</app-table>
```

**app-table.component.ts**

```typescript
@Component({
  selector: 'app-table',
  template: `
    <div *ngFor="let line of data">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="lineHeaderTmpl, 
                     context: { $implicit: line }"></ng-container>
      <div *ngFor="let element of line.values">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="lineContentTmpl, 
                       context: { $implicit: element }"></ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class AppTableComponent  {
  @Input() data: any;

  @ContentChild('lineHeader') lineHeaderTmpl: TemplateRef<any>; 
  @ContentChild('lineContent') lineContentTmpl: TemplateRef<any>; 
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xovwu7?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: I heard about `ContentChild` but didn't succeed to use it efficiently. Thanks!

Comment: THIIIIISSSSSSS!

Comment: This is awesome. One thing though... is it possible to detect if ng-template exists and if it doesn't exist, then show default?

Comment: @rain01 in the above example you could just check to see if the template was found `const noTemplate = !this.lineHeaderTmpl.length;` and show some other content. I've had success using this method in the past: [Gist](https://gist.github.com/benjamincharity/1d81649150a584d9c8673c508afd46d7)

Comment: This is beautiful :')

Comment: Any chance to make this work in a hybrid app (with AngularJS 1)? It's impossible to use ng-template in downgraded components...