# Angular - conditional div container around <router-outlet>

Tags: angular, angular7

In my app.component.html I want to render certain div containers based on the current url. For example

#### 1. If current URL is authenticate render the following

```
<div *ngIf="'authenticate' === this.currentUrl">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

#### 2. If current URL is not authenticate, render the following

```
<div *ngIf="'authenticate' !== this.currentUrl" id="wrapper">
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row extranet-outlet-wrapper">
                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am not using any child routes. It is because, I want a different layout only for authenticate component and the rest remains same.

This is working when it first loads, but when I click on any `[routerLink]` the view does not gets updated. However if I reload the screen it works. The issue is with the conditional rendering of `<router-outlet>` in `app.component.html`, I checked this by removing the condition and it works just fine.

Can someone help me understand what is happening here and how to go about fixing this if possible without using child routes.

Comment: can you create a demo code on stackblitz.com ? It would help me understand what you are trying to achieve. May be we can suggest a better way to implement.

Comment: Can you try with named router-outlet one for authenticate and not authenticate for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38038001/multiple-named-router-outlet-angular-2

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699469/how-to-use-multiple-ng-content-in-the-same-component-in-angular-2/44699654#44699654

Comment: Thank you @yurzui, that link helped. The solution was to use if else using ng-template and it started working again. The first div I used `<div *ngIf="'authenticate' !== this.currentUrl else authenticate" id="wrapper">` and the second one replaced with `<ng-template #authenticate>` and it works without any issues.

Comment: That's because Angular only recognizes the first router-outlet

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try this solution.

```
<ng-container
  *ngIf="'authenticate' !== this.currentUrl; then notauthenticated; else authenticate">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #notauthenticated>
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="row extranet-outlet-wrapper">
                        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #authenticate>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: This works, but why not only making one *ngIf container and one else for the other case (skip then)? 2 code blocks instead of 3... is there any good reason?

Comment: You can do both. This way of doing it is to have a more clean code, I think, and to separate concerns. Anyway here's the Angular docs for Ngif https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#description

Answer (score 2):

Angular provides a Directive [routerLinkActive], which takes as input the array of classes that will be added if a specific part of the route included in the url.

**Usage**

**app.component.html**

```
<div class="main-container" [routerLinkActive]="['app-active-class']">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**pages.component.html**

```
<div class="page-category">
  <a [routerLink]="1" [routerLinkActive]="['page-category-active-class']">Num_1</a>
  <a [routerLink]="2" [routerLinkActive]="['page-category-active-class']">Num_2</a>
</div>
<div class="page-view">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**page.component.html**

```
<div class="page-num">
  {{ page_num }}
</div>
```

**page.component.ts**

```
import { ActivatedRoute } from "@angular/router";

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

ngOnInit() {
  page_num = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("page_num")
}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
...
{ path: "page", component: PagesComponent },
{ path: "page/:page_num", component: PageComponent },
...
```