# How to render the same content in multiple places in the child component?

Tags: angular, typescript

How to render the content of `ng-content` in the component and the menu?

I try to do using the answer from this question [How to use multiple ng-content in the same component in Angular 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44699469/how-to-use-multiple-ng-content-in-the-same-component-in-angular-2), But it's not works as expected.

When I open the menu then the buttons **are disappear** from the component.

How to fix that? I want to have the buttons in the component and in the menu.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9ssgdr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcontainer.ts)

usage:

```
  <container>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="foo()">foo</button>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="bar()">bar</button>
  </container>
```

container:

```
  <section id="buttons">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl"></ng-container>
  </section>
  
  <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>
  <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="contentTpl"></ng-container> 
  </mat-menu>

  <ng-template #contentTpl><ng-content></ng-content></ng-template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is because it only render in one `<ng-content>`. You can use `<ng-template>` to solve that.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'container',
  template: `
    <section id="buttons">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
    </section>
  
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">Menu</button>

    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container> 
    </mat-menu>
  `,
})
export class Container {
  @Input() content: TemplateRef<any>;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'menu-overview-example',
  template: `
    <container [content]="content"></container>

    <ng-template #content>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="foo()">foo</button>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="bar()">bar</button>
    </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class MenuOverviewExample {}
```

Or you can place the `<ng-template>` inside the tags:

```
<container>
    <ng-template>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="foo()">foo</button>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="bar()">bar</button>
    </ng-template>
</container>
```

And:

```
@ContentChild(TemplateRef) content: TemplateRef<any>;
```

Comment: Is it possible to keep the syntax without ng-template?
`<container>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="foo()">foo</button>
        <button mat-raised-button (click)="bar()">bar</button>
</container>
` or maybe wrap the `button` in component?