# How do I conditionally wrap <ng-content> multiple times?

Tags: angular, angular2-ngcontent

I tried writing a wrapper component which can be passed some text and some parameters, which would then format my text using bootstrap, based on these parameters.

I've tried this:

**header-line.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector:'header-line',
  templateUrl: 'header-line.component.html'
})
export class HeaderLineComponent {
  @Input level: number;
  // other inputs used for formatting skipped here
}
```

**header-line.component.html**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12"> <!-- would really be [className]="..." based on skipped inputs -->
    <header-wrapper [level]="level">
      <!-- display of icon, based on skipped inputs -->
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </header-wrapper>
  </div>
</div>
```

**header-wrapper.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'header-wrapper',
  templateUrl: './header-wrapper.component.html'
})
export class HeaderWrapperComponent {
  @Input() level: number;
}
```

**header-wrapper.component.html**

```
<h1 *ngIf="level === 1"><ng-content></ng-content></h1>
<h2 *ngIf="level === 2"><ng-content></ng-content></h2>
<h3 *ngIf="level === 3"><ng-content></ng-content></h3>
<h4 *ngIf="level === 4"><ng-content></ng-content></h4>
<h5 *ngIf="level === 5"><ng-content></ng-content></h5>
<span *ngIf="!level || level < 1 || level > 5"><ng-content></ng-content></span>
```

**Intended usage**

Usage would be something along the lines of:

```
<header-line [level]="1" [...]="...">Just a test h1</header-line>
<header-line [level]="2" [...]="...">Just a test h2</header-line>
<header-line [level]="3" [...]="...">Just a test h3</header-line>
<header-line [...]="...">Just a test span</header-line>
```

**Expected output**

I would then have expected the output to create something equivalent to:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols-sm-12">
    <h1>Just a test h1</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols-sm-12">
    <h2>Just a test h2</h2>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols-sm-12">
    <h3>Just a test h3</h3>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols-sm-12">
    <span>Just a test span</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Effective output**

However, what I do get is the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols-sm-12">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols-sm-12">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols-sm-12">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="cols-sm-12">
    <span>Just a test span</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Problem analysis**

It took me only a little while to find out that the cause of my problem is the repeated use of  in header-wrapper.component.ts because it is apparently static and cannot be used dynamically.

The following two links explain why my expectations were disappointed:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9173

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8563

**Finding a solution**

The following link on Stackoverflow shows how this can be done if only two cases need to be supported:

[How to conditionally wrap a div around ng-content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41593973/how-to-conditionally-wrap-a-div-around-ng-content)

Using that approach I managed the following:

**Updated: header-wrapper.component.html**

```
<h1 *ngIf="level && level === 1; else notOne">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
</h1>

<ng-template #notOne>
  <h2 *ngIf="level && level === 2; else notTwo">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
  </h2>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #notTwo>
  <h3 *ngIf="level && level === 3; else notThree">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
  </h3>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #notThree>
  <h4 *ngIf="level && level === 4; else notFour">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
  </h4>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #notFour>
  <h5 *ngIf="level && level === 5; else content">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content"></ng-container>
  </h5>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #content>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</ng-template>
```

This produces the desired output.

**My question**

Is this really the only way to do this? Or is there an easier way that I am missing?

Comment: The updated approach is the correct way to embed transcluded content in multiple places. Theres no more to it. You might want to watch https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTwKhxLZ3jI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the video linked by Jota.Toledo I have come up with a more compact version.

**Updated header-wrapper.component.html**

```
<h1 *ngIf="level && level === 1"><ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container></h1>
<h2 *ngIf="level && level === 2"><ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container></h2>
<h3 *ngIf="level && level === 3"><ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container></h3>
<h4 *ngIf="level && level === 4"><ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container></h4>
<h5 *ngIf="level && level === 5"><ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container></h5>
<span *ngIf="!level || level < 1 || level > 5"><ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"></ng-container></span>
```

This works just the same as my updated solution from the question, but I find this version more compact and more easily readable.